# Is it possible to access local network device API using dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am running device in my local network. It has REST API, I can query it by http://192.168.0.X/api/method

Is it possible to:
1. Find local device IP address
2. Send queries to API
?

I know I can send requests to public endpoints. Is there any workaround to access local device?

Comment: use something like `ngrok`

Comment: @sid8491 yes I can do it for my own purpose but I want provide solution for more people so this is not a resolution :(

Comment: then upload your code to cloud, ec2 or heroku etc

Comment: @sid8491 I can't. This is third party device running in local network

Comment: I think the only way for now is plugging new self-controlled device to local network which will proxy API requests.